# Spacing between horizontal in-line un-ordered list overflow

Tags: html, css

**[CLICK FOR LIVE DEMO HERE](https://hassanalthaf.com)**

As you see below, the list works perfectly if the screen is wide enough, however, when the screen becomes shorter, of course the horizontal list would not fit within the screen, so it will break to the next line.

[image: Picture 1]

The breaking of the list becomes like this:

[image]

How would I increase the spacing between the link elements if such an event occurs?

The complete code is below:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>HassanAlthaf.com</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center page">
        <div class="row col-8">
            <div class="row col-12 header">
                <h1>HassanAlthaf<span class="highlight">.com</span></h1>
                <p>An undergraduate student looking to grow in a professional environment to take off his career as a Software Developer.</p>
            </div>

            <ul class="links">
                <li class="link">
                    <a href="#">Facebook</a>
                </li>
                <li class="link">
                    <a href="#">LinkedIn</a>
                </li>
                <li class="link">
                    <a href="#">GitHub</a>
                </li>
                <li class="link">
                    <a href="#">Instagram</a>
                </li>
                <li class="link">
                    <a href="#">StackOverflow</a>
                </li>
                <li class="link">
                    <a href="#">Email</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="/node_modules/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.css:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SF-Pro';
    src: url("../fonts/SF-Pro-Display-Bold.otf");
    font-weight: bold;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SF-Pro';
    src: url("../fonts/SF-Pro-Display-LightItalic.otf");
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'SF-Pro';
    src: url("../fonts/SF-Pro-Display-Regular.otf");
    font-weight: normal;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

.page {
    background: #000000;
    height: 100vh;
}

.links {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.link {
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.link a {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: "SF-Pro", sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #2196f3;
    padding: 10px;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
}

.header h1 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'SF-Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 55px;
}

.header p {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: 'SF-Pro', sans-serif;
    color: #FCFCFC;
}

.highlight {
    color: #2196f3;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Add margin bottom for each one of the list items.

Comment: @mahan Yes I've already tried that, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: That is because link is `inline`. Inline elements does not have margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to use Flexbox like the following:

```css
.links {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;

  // Add this lines
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.link {
    display: inline;
    width: auto;
  height: auto;
    text-align: center;

  // And this line
  margin: 20px 5px;
  
}
```

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/syed_n_sakib/pen/zYOyBOe?editors=1100)

Comment: The codepen is close but you've missed off the horizontal gaps between items.

Comment: Yeah, I've missed the horizontal gaps. I've edited my code.

Comment: Close, adjective : near, approaching.

Comment: Oh! I thought the link is broken. :D :D

Answer (score 1):

Simply give your `.link`class a display of `link{display:inline-block}` then you can set the margins too.
You have to remove the `width:100%` you set to the `.link`, that's like setting them to display block and overriding your `display:inline-block`. 
When you're done, you can throw in a `margin:15px 0px` on `.link` to make the presentation better.

Comment: Tried that too. `inline-block` doesn't work, makes it a vertical list.

Comment: @HassanAlthaf hope the new edit solves the problem.